# If I set float left the height is not working

Tags: jquery, css

If I set float left the height of the jquery is not working 
The website is http://imperiorwebdesign.com/portofoliu
I set the height in css but I don't like how it works

```
(function($) {

    $.Tabs = function(el, options) {

        var base = this;
        base.$el = $(el);
        base.$nav = base.$el.find(".nav");

        base.init = function() {

            base.options = $.extend({},$.Tabs.defaultOptions, options);

            // Accessible hiding fix
            $(".hide").css({
                "position": "relative",
                "top": 0,
                "left": 0,
                "display": "none"
            }); 

            base.$nav.delegate("li > a", "click", function() {

                // Figure out current list via CSS class
                var curList = base.$el.find("a.current").attr("href").substring(1),

                // List moving to
                    $newList = $(this),

                // Figure out ID of new list
                    listID = $newList.attr("href").substring(1),

                // Set outer wrapper height to (static) height of current inner list
                    $allListWrap = base.$el.find(".list-wrap"),
                    curListHeight = $allListWrap.height();
                $allListWrap.height(curListHeight);

                if ((listID != curList) && ( base.$el.find(":animated").length == 0)) {

                    // Fade out current list
                    base.$el.find("#"+curList).fadeOut(base.options.speed, function() {

                        // Fade in new list on callback
                        base.$el.find("#"+listID).fadeIn(base.options.speed);

                        // Adjust outer wrapper to fit new list snuggly
                        var newHeight = base.$el.find("#"+listID).height();
                        $allListWrap.animate({
                            height: newHeight
                        });

                        // Remove highlighting - Add to just-clicked tab
                        base.$el.find(".nav li a").removeClass("current");
                        $newList.addClass("current");

                    });

                }   

                // Don't behave like a regular link
                // Stop propegation and bubbling
                return false;
            });

        };
        base.init();
    };

    $.Tabs.defaultOptions = {
        "speed": 300
    };

    $.fn.Tabs = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            (new $.Tabs(this, options));
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
$(function() {

      $("#pagew").Tabs({
            "speed": 200
      });

});`
```

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that shows your issue?

Comment: "If I set float" - on which element? "The height of jquery" - you mean setting the height via jQuery? On which element? Where is your html? What exactly means not working? And so on,... Please be more explicit with your statements.

Comment: if I set the piture in css to float left, the height is not working... the html is http://imperiorwebdesign.com/portofoliu and is the one with tabs, with white (the one with pictures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like a clearing issue to me you probably need to add a clear to the surrounding div.

here is a good article on the subject - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 0):

With the style (`float: left`) also set (`overflow: auto`);